# Contents From Two Divs to One Input Field Value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to insert the contents of the two divs into a single input field in a form. 
This is what I have so far but at the moment the only field that copies over when the onclick occurs is the edit1 div contents.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

The JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function copyText2() {
var output = document.getElementById("edit1","edit2").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("user-submitted-tags").value = output;
}
</script>
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="edit1">foo</div>
<div id="edit2">bar</div>

<form>
<input class="usp_input" type="text" name="user-submitted-tags" id="user-submitted-tags" value="">

<input onClick="copyText2()" class="usp_input" type="submit" name="user-submitted-post" id="user-submitted-post" value="Submit Post">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the two contents separately, and then add them.

```
var output1 = document.getElementById("edit1").innerHTML;
var output2 = document.getElementById("edit2").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("user-submitted-tags").value = output1 + "&nbsp;" + output2;
```

Comment: this is almost getting to what i wanted. how would i put a space between the two entries from with the values from edit1 & edit2? They seem to be combined into one value in the text field.

Comment: Try adding a non blocking space between them (updated answer).

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var output = document.getElementById("edit1","edit2").innerHTML;
```

into

```
var output = document.getElementById("edit1").innerHTML + document.getElementById("edit2").innerHTML;
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should copy them one at a time and then concatenate

```
function copyText2() {
    var output = "";

    output += document.getElementById("edit1").innerHTML;

    output += document.getElementById("edit2").innerHTML;

    document.getElementById("user-submitted-tags").value = output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("")` is only using the first id string you give it. It doesn't accept multiple ids. From the [Mozilla Dev docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById):

```
id is a case-sensitive string representing the unique ID of the 
element being sought.
```

Just have `output` grab the content from the first id, then from the second and append them together.